# How can I read Chinese TEXT from a PDF file using PoDoFo's "podofotxtextract" (C++) sample

Tags: c++, windows, pdf, podofo

I am using PoDoFo 0.9.1 library to read a PDF file which contains Chinese characters on Win32 XP Chinese version OS.
  I found PoDoFo's sample project "podofotxtextract" can read PDF in English gracefully, however, when I opened a Chinese PDF file, nothing parsed out. anyone has suggestion? thanks a lot.

Comment: That's what is nice about open source, you can fix the bugs yourself.

Comment: @ chinloon - can you share how you used the podofo library in your project or can your share me some sample :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Objective C to add an annotation on an existing PDF file.
btw: just try

> PdfString pdfString(reinterpret_cast<const pdf_utf8*>("the chars you read ..."));

that's some code below ...

```
PdfPage* pPage = doc->GetPage(pageIndex);
if (! pPage) {
    // couldn't get that page 
    return;
}
PdfAnnotation* anno;

anno = pPage->CreateAnnotation(ePdfAnnotation_Text, rect);

PdfString sTitle(reinterpret_cast<const pdf_utf8*>([@"中国" UTF8String]));
PdfString sContent(reinterpret_cast<const pdf_utf8*>([@"这是一个中文测试"UTF8String]));
// to parse this annotation
// anno->GetContents().GetStringUtf8().c_str()
anno->SetTitle(sTitle);
anno->SetContents(sContent);
anno->SetOpen(bOpen);
```